# ¿Extraer información de otro excel en modo lectura?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

tengo una macro en excel(excel A) que coge datos de otro excel(excel B) de manera automática cada x tiempo y luego los trato(excel A).

El problema que me encuentro, es que si tengo abierto el excel B, la macro se me queja y me dice "si quiero guardar los datos no guardados en el excel B" y la parte automática pierde su sentido.

Hay alguna linea de codigo(para macros) que copie la informacion del excel B, de manera que lo haga en "modo lectura" y asi evitarme este problema? O alguna otra solución práctica?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Este es mi codigo actual:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "ExcelB.xlsx" _
        , UpdateLinks:=0
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    Range("A4:E15").Copy
    Windows("ExcelA").Activate
```

El problema que me encuentro es que esta manera, abre el excel en modo escritura, y si tengo abierto el excel me lo cierra o se queja de que si quireo guardar algun cambio.
Me gustaría que esto no pasará, intentando implementar alguna opción como que abriera el excel en "modo lectura".
Gracias.

Comment: Podrías anexar el código con el que estas trabajando hasta ahora, así les será más sencillo a los miembros de la comunidad poder orientarte.

Comment: No creo que aporte mucho, pero lo pongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En VBA, cuando se utiliza el método `Workbooks.Open`, uno de los argumentos (el tercero, concretamente) precisamente es si quieres abrir el libro en modo solo lectura.

Prueba así a ver que tal:

```
Dim LibroSecundario As Workbook
Set LibroSecundario = Application.Workbooks.Open("ExcelB.xlsx", False, True)
Sheets("Hoja1").Select
Range("A4:E15").Copy
Windows("ExcelA").Activate

'Resto de tu código
'
'
'
'
'
'
'Al final, cuando cierres libro B
LibroSecundario.Close False
```

> [Workbooks.Open (método)
>   (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel)

Comment: Funciona!! He conseguido evitar que me salga el mensaje de alerta, pero me cierra el excelB si lo tengo abierto, y me gustaría que no.

Comment: Si no quieres cerrar el ExcelB, simplemente elimina de mi código la línea que dice `LibroSecundario.Close False`. Y si la respuesta te ha ayudado, por favor, márcala como correcta, y así se queda cerrada la pregunta.